# Erro do PHP ao tentar puxar dados de Banco MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, servidor

Bom dia galera, beleza ? Estou com um problema no seguinte. Hospedei meu site PHP em um Servidor onde há o DNS e o sufixo principal da rede, isto para que o site só consiga ser acessado de maneira interna na empresa. No meu PC onde eu uso o WampServer, a aplicação funciona normalmente, mas depois que passei para o Servidor e repliquei o Banco de Dados, com a mesma Senha, nome da DB e etc.. passou a me dar este erro. Alguem consegue me dizer o por que ?

OBS: O erro ocorre mesmo tanto se eu entrar pelo localhost do Servidor tanto pelo link direto qual o site está hospedado. Já fiz testes de conexão diretamente no MySQL WorkBench e funcionou normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha conexão está da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
$servidor = 'Mysql@localhost:3306';
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '*******';
$dbname = 'valevip';

$connect = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);


if ($connect -> connect_error){
    die("Conexão falhou: " . $connect->connect_error);
}
```

E por fim como a conexão aparece para mim no WorkBench:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Basicamente você não fez a verificação da conexão, e acabou usando um `$servidor` inválido na sequência

Comment: @Bacco eu mudei a maneira que fiz a conexão, agora apareceu erros diferentes, e não mais o de conexão. Nas minhas pesquisas, retornaram erros do tipo ```PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, bool given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\valevip\index.php on line 19```. Alguns retornaram em bool outros em null.

Comment: Ainda é o mesmo motivo, você deixou passar um erro da conexão sem tratar ou está usando a variável errada no 1o parâmetro.